# Compiler macro to test difference between uint64_t and unsigned long long int

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, uint64, unsigned-long-long-int

I have C++11 code that is failing to compile because an overloaded function is redefined with the same types as arguments:

```
char const* foo(uint64_t) { return "%" PRIu64; }
char const* foo(unsigned long long int) { return "%llu"; }
```

Is there a compiler macro I can add to check equality between these two primitives, and then excise the second if it is equivalent, before compilation?

There are other functions that return character pointers for other types. For instance, adding this does not cause me any trouble, even though a `signed` and an `unsigned long long int` use the same number of bytes:

```
char const* foo(long long int) { return "%lld"; }
```

So it seems insufficient to check how much memory a type uses. What are other approaches?

Comment: No need for a macro with SFINAE.

Comment: Have you checked for some standard library support for determining the printf specifiers from type?

Comment: Change the return value of the second overload to :  enable_if<is_same<uint64_t, unsigned long long int>::value, const typename char *>::type;  This is what @chris is saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the maximum values of these type using the definitions from `climits` and `cstdint`:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>

char const* foo(uint64_t) { return "%" PRIu64; }

//ULLONG_MAX defined in climits, UINT64_MAX in cstdint
#if ULLONG_MAX != UINT64_MAX

char const* foo(unsigned long long int) { return "%llu"; }

#endif
```

It would probably be a better long-term solution however to create a system using templates.

Comment: This is brittle since `ULLONG_MAX` could be different than `UINT64_MAX` in a different platform.

Comment: @RSahu: "could be different" (or rather, could be the same) is the point.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, what if `unsigned long long int` is `uint128_t` (not sure there such a thing)? The `#if` statement has to be expanded to take care of that possibility.

Comment: @RSahu The fact that they could be different is the whole point of not the this answer but the original question. In the event that they are the same, only one function is defined; in the event that they are different, two functions are defined. How does this not solve the original problem?